# Comparing tuple to int on Python

Tags: python

I'm traing to compare the components of an tuple in Python to find bigest and the smallest, but my code just returns the two latest components of the touple, and I have no idea why:

```
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
numbers2=numbers.split()
numbers2=tuple(numbers2)
i=0
gran=numbers2[0]
petit=numbers2[0]
for i in range (len(numbers2)):
    if numbers2[i]>gran:
    gran=numbers2[i]
print(gran)
j=0
for j in range (len(numbers2)):
    if numbers[j]<petit:
    petit=numbers2[j]
print(petit)
resultat= gran+" "+petit
print(resultat)
```

I got "6 -6" in return. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Your tuple is not a tuple of integers but a tuple of strings. convert the tuple to a tuple of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your splitted string into integers before turning it into a tuple.

```python
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
numbers2=[int(x) for x in numbers.split()]
numbers2=tuple(numbers2)
...
```

You can also merge those two operations into a single line.

```python
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
numbers2=tuple([int(x) for x in numbers.split()])
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have already mentioned that the items need to be converted to integers. I wanted to also mention that there are `min` and `max` functions available.

```
>>> numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
>>> numbers_tuple=tuple(int(i) for i in numbers.split())
>>> min(numbers_tuple)
-214
>>> max(numbers_tuple)
542
```

This also avoids creating an initial list like many of the previous answers, but using a generator expression in the `tuple()` instantiation rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: I didn't know there was a generator expression for tuples like lists. Nice :D

Comment: Generator expressions are a thing on their own. try `print (i for i in range(10))` or `print (i for i in range(10)).next()`

Answer (score 0):

Your tuple is a tuple of strings, not a tuple of integers. You need to convert your tuple to a tuple of integers:

```
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
numbers2=numbers.split()
numbers2 = [int(i) for i in numbers2] # convert tuple of strs to tuple of ints
```

Fully working program:

```
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
numbers2=numbers.split()
numbers2 = [int(i) for i in numbers2] # convert tuple of strs to tuple of ints
numbers2=tuple(numbers2)
i=0
gran=numbers2[0]
petit=numbers2[0]
for i in range (len(numbers2)):
    if numbers2[i]>gran:
        gran=numbers2[i]
print(gran)
j=0
for j in range (len(numbers2)):
    if numbers2[j]<petit:
        petit=numbers2[j]
print(petit)
resultat= str(gran)+" "+str(petit)
print(resultat)
```

Output:

```
542
-214
542 -214
>>>
```

I should note, you program could be written much simpler than what you currently have:

```
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"

# convert the numbers string to a tuple of integers
num_lst = tuple([int(i) for i in numbers.split()])

# take a guess and say the
# highest and lowest are both
# the first element in num_lst
lowest = num_lst[0]
highest = num_lst[0]

# iterate through the
# num_lst. No need to
# initizalize i beforehand
for i in num_lst:
    # if we find a higher number
    # then our guess of the highest
    # number, reassign highest to that number
    if i > highest:
        highest = i
    # if we find a lower number
    # then our guess of the lowest
    # number, reassign lowest to that number
    elif i < lowest:
        lowest = i

# print the highest and lowest number
print("Highest:", highest, " Lowest:", lowest)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be taken down to a simple two lines:

```
numbers=tuple([int (a) for a in "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6".split()])
print(str(max(numbers)) + ' ' + str(min(numbers)))
```

The values are initially inserted as a string therefore must be cast to an integer to do comparisons. When printing the results, if you want them to be printed on the same line with a space inbetween then you can cast the numbers back to strings

A more elegent way to do this would be to not use a string to state the numbers, instead use an array:

```
numbers=tuple([4, 5, 29, 54, 4, 0, -214, 542, -64, 1, -3, 6, -6])
print(str(max(numbers)) + ' ' + str(min(numbers)))
```